# Why my server can not respond to the client's request from the webbrowser?

Tags: c#, sockets

i'm working on Embedded sensor cloud (Client - Server) program using C# and there is a problem that is out of my knowledge and i need your help :D

Below you can see my server side code and the problem that i have is that,  whenever i run the program in Debug mode everything works pretty well but if i run it like normal my request for opening a HTML file from my Localhost does not work and the browser send some null request instead to the server and it can not go further.

this is my server side code:

```
private static void Listen()
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8081);

        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Connection");
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                Console.WriteLine("connected");
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(handler);

                if (stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    Request req = new Request(stream);
                    Dictionary<string, string> header = new Dictionary<string, string>(req.Headers);
                    PluginManager ipm = new PluginManager();
                    IPlugin plug = SelectPlugin(ipm, req);

                    if (plug != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in header)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }

                        IResponse rep = plug.Handle(req);
                        rep.Send(stream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");

                        stream.Close();
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IResponse resp = new Response()
                        {
                            StatusCode = 404,
                            ContentType = "text/html",
                        };
                        resp.Send(stream);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Data not Available");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is what i get when i run in Debug mode:

```
Waiting for Connection
connected
[get .../index.html HTTP/1.1]
[user-agent, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134]
[accept-language, en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,fa;q=0.2]
[accept, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]
[upgrade-insecure-requests, 1]
[accept-encoding, gzip, deflate]
[host, 8081]
[connection, Keep-Alive]
Success
```

and here when i run it normal:

```
 Waiting for Connection
 connected
 Data not Available
 Waiting for Connection
```

the socket can not listen for incoming connection any more. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** use `DataAvailable` to make decisions other than "async vs sync". It doesn't tell you whether data *will* be available - it only tells you whether it is available **right now**. I suspect that debug mode is slowing it down sufficiently that the data is available. You should instead do a read (sync or async, your choice), with a non-positive read result meaning end of stream.

That said: it looks like you've written a server that scales to one concurrent client. Unless this is for local usage, I would advise not writing your own server here - it might be easier to start from "kestrel" (the asp.net core server), and implement your own handler there.

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you also know why generally my localhost send automatically some invalid request to the server? i mean like without clicking on Enter or something it sends some null data to the server, which is weird cause i didn't ask to do it.

Comment: @brk I don't see any evidence of an invalid request; just... you didn't wait for it